# typescript error running navalia example

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, typescript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run this example from https://github.com/joelgriffith/navalia but for the light of me, I couldn't get it to work without error:

**navaliatest.ts**

```
/// <reference path="typings.d.ts" />

import { Chrome } from 'navalia';
const chrome = new Chrome();

async function buyItOnAmazon() {
  const url = await chrome.goto('https://amazon.com');
  const typed = await chrome.type('input', 'Kindle');
  const clicked = await chrome.click('.nav-search-submit input');

  chrome.done();

  console.log(url, typed, clicked); // 'https://www.amazon.com/', true, true
}

buyItOnAmazon();
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "files": [
    "navaliatest.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "*" : ["/usr/local/lib/node_modules/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/navalia/build/Chrome.d.ts" />

declare module 'navalia' {
  var Chrome: any;
  export = Chrome;
}
```

Below are the versions:

```
MacBook-Pro:testcasperjs myusername$ node --version
v6.11.2MacBook-Pro:testcasperjs myusername$ npm --version
3.10.10
MacBook-Pro:testcasperjs myusername$ tsc --version
Version 2.4.2
```

This is the error I got although I do get .js file output:

```
MacBook-Pro:testcasperjs myusername$ tsc navaliatest.ts
../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/navalia/node_modules/chrome-launcher/chrome-finder.ts(203,16): error TS2339: Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.
../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/navalia/node_modules/chrome-launcher/chrome-launcher.ts(99,15): error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.
navaliatest.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module ''navalia'' has no exported member 'Chrome'.
```

I am sure there is a stupid mistake somewhere but please could someone help me and take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to redeclare `navalia`. It has already been done for you at [`node_modules/navalia/build/index.d.ts`](https://github.com/joelgriffith/navalia/blob/master/src/index.ts) given that `moduleResolution` is set to `Node`

You'll need to set `module` to `commonjs` so that you can run it in node

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "files": [
    "navaliatest.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  }
}
```

**navaliatest.ts** (No change)

```
import { Chrome } from 'navalia';
const chrome = new Chrome();

async function buyItOnAmazon() {
  const url = await chrome.goto('https://amazon.com');
  const typed = await chrome.type('input', 'Kindle');
  const clicked = await chrome.click('.nav-search-submit input');

  chrome.done();

  console.log(url, typed, clicked); // 'https://www.amazon.com/', true, true
}

buyItOnAmazon();
```

It'll create `navaliatest.js` with no errors, which can be run in node.

Comment: I got this error `error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'`

Comment: The error you must be because of tsconfig not being read, which sets target as es6 thereby recognising `Promise`